# Sinusodial equation help

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are the steps to solving this equation?

$$4 \cos(10x) + 2 = 2.$$

I get all the way to cos(10)x = 0. I am relearning precalculus and using Khan Academy. I cannot understand how he does one thing. I understand the identity cos(x) = cos(-x). I do not understand how he gets cos(x) = cos(x+360). Then Khan states 10x = 90 deg + n * 360 deg. That is the part where I am lost.

Comment: Do you know how to solve $\cos x=\beta$?

Comment: All the trigonometric functions are $360^\circ$-periodic. Therefore, $\sin(x+360^\circ)=\sin x$ and $\cos(x+360^\circ)=\cos x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Can you solve $4t + 2 = 2$ for $t$?

**Hint 2:** If you know the value of $\cos(\theta)$, can you find $\theta$?  For example, if $\cos(\theta) = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$, what is $\theta$?  What if $\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{3}$?  What if $\cos(\theta) = t$?

---

Based on your edit, I might suggest thinking about the problem slightly differently.  You know that
$$\cos(10x) = 0.$$
Remember that $\cos$ eats angles, and spits out numbers that represent the $x$-coordinates of points on the unit circle (as an aside, this is why I think that it is unforgivable for textbook authors to give trigonometric equations where $x$ or $y$ represent the unknown---better to avoid confusion by using some other variable, such as $t$).

With that in mind, the number $10x$ represents an *angle*, and we know that the cosine of that angle is 0.  This means that the ray originating at the origin which makes an angle of $10x$ with the $x$-axis intersects the unit circle at a point with $x$-coordinate 0.  There are two such points:  $90^\circ$ and $-90^{\circ}$.  Thus it must be that
$$ 10x = \pm 90^\circ.$$
...almost.

Remember that $\cos$ is $360^{\circ}$-periodic.  That means that it repeats values every $360^{\circ}$.  More formally, we know that
$$ \cos(\theta+360^{\circ}) = \cos(\theta)$$
for all angles $\theta$.  Thus if $\cos(10x) = 0$, then $\cos(10x+360^{\circ}$ will also be zero.  Indeed,
$$\cos(10x+360^{\circ}k) = 0$$
for any integer (i.e. $\pm 1,\pm 2,\pm 3,\dotsc$) $k$.  Going back to what we concluded above, this implies that
\begin{align}
10x+360^{\circ}k = \pm 90^{\circ}
&\implies 10x = \pm 90^{\circ} - 360^{\circ}k \\
&\implies x = \pm 9^{\circ} - 36^{\circ}k.
\end{align}
Since the sign of $k$ doesn't matter, we could rewrite this as
$$ x = 36k^\circ \pm 9^{\circ}, $$
where $k$ is any integer.  It might also be better to say that the solutions to the original equation are the elements of the set
$$\{  36k^\circ \pm 9^{\circ} : k\in\mathbb{Z}\}, $$
which you can show via some clever manipulation is really just
$$\{  18k^\circ + 9^{\circ} : k\in\mathbb{Z}\}. $$

Comment: modulo $180$, not $360$

Comment: @Furrane What is written is correct.  Note that $\pm$.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily solve for $\cos(10x)$ :

$$4\cos(10x)+2 = 2$$

$$4\cos(10x) +2 -2 = 2-2$$

$$4\cos(10x) = 0$$

$$\cos(10x) = 0$$

Now before thinking about $x$ let's note $u = 10x$ and re-write the equation :

$$\cos(10x) = \cos(u) = 0$$

Now for which angles do we have this equality ? Let's look at the trigonometric circle :

[image: trigonometric circle]

You can see that if $\cos(u) = 0 $ then $u={\pi\over 2} +n\pi $ which is, in degrees, $u=(90 + n*180) \deg $

Now to find $x$ we just have to substitute in our formula $u=10x$ :

$$u=(90 + n*180) \deg = 10x$$

$$ x={(90+n*180)\over 10}\deg$$

$$ x = 9 +18n\deg, n\in \mathbb{Z}$$